# Order media in ascending mode QBImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using [QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker) to allow user to select images from gallery.

```
QBImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [QBImagePickerController new];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.mediaType = QBImagePickerMediaTypeImage;
imagePickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
imagePickerController.showsNumberOfSelectedAssets = YES;
self.imagePickerControllerImages = imagePickerController;

[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerControllerImages animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The only issue is that images are ordered in ascending mode, that means the **older** **images** are **presented first**, the user needs to scroll until the end to reach the newest images every time.

Is there a way to order in descending mode?

Like Facebook and WhatsApp that let you choose images starting by the newest.

Comment: Seem like the library doesn't have such public API. Try to ask on GitHub or implement it by yourself with PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-line fix in `QBAssetsViewController.m`:

```
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
self.fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetCollection options:options];
```